# Codesept alert window testing in chrome headless mode

Tags: selenium, webdriver, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser, codeceptjs

Codceptjs tests are failing if I have alert/confirm popup in the app, and running browser in headless mode.
Did try `await I.acceptPopup();` and this isn't working in headless mode. Would by highly appreciated for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

you need to write more details ,
Please better run it with ui on to see if something wrong by eyes, you also set pause before dialog and try to debug  ,
Also maybe the dialog isn't their?